# How to sanitize grape params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

I want to mass update attributes of an entity.

How can I sanitize properly the params which is coming from grape?

This is my console log about the parameters:

```
params.except(:route_info, :token, :id)
=> {"display_number"=>"7"}
[18] pry(#<Grape::Endpoint>)> params.permit(:display_number)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
from /Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@thelocker/gems/hashie-2.0.5/lib/hashie/mash.rb:207:in `default'
[19] pry(#<Grape::Endpoint>)> params.sanitize
=> nil
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In grape you need to declare your params before the actual method.

Within the method the `params` object is a `Hashie::Mash` instance, and does not have APIs like `permit` and `sanitize`...

[Here](https://github.com/intridea/grape#parameter-validation-and-coercion) is the relevant documentation for declaring and validating parameters in grape:

> You can define validations and coercion options for your parameters
>   using a `params` block.
>
> ```
> params do
>   requires :id, type: Integer
>   optional :text, type: String, regexp: /^[a-z]+$/
>   group :media do
>     requires :url
>   end
>   optional :audio do
>     requires :format, type: Symbol, values: [:mp3, :wav, :aac, :ogg], default: :mp3
>   end
>   mutually_exclusive :media, :audio
> end
> put ':id' do
>   # params[:id] is an Integer
> end
> ```
>
> When a type is specified an implicit validation is done after the
>   coercion to ensure the output type is the one declared.

If you still want to use strong parameters, you'll need to use the [`strong_parameters`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem, and create a new instance of `ActionController::Paramter` [yourself](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#use-outside-of-controllers):

> ```
> raw_parameters = { :email => "john@example.com", :name => "John", :admin => true }
> parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_parameters)
> user = User.create(parameters.permit(:name, :email))
> ```

Comment: Thank Uri Agassi, I knew these... I am using it across the app. This also means that I can't bulk update entity attributes... Did I understand correctly?

Comment: See my update regarding using strong parameters outside of a rails controller

Comment: Thanks this is the way I wanted :)

Comment: Thanks @UriAgassi! I was wondering, does params block only apply to the next GET/POST/PUT/DELETE method, or does it then require params for all GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods in the class? Additionally, if params are nested in request body (i.e. I access them through `params[:something][:property]`), how would I declare them as required? (syntax question)